# Why doesn't my sinon fake server return anything?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to setup a fake sinon server for testing some requests. In the code below, my callback function never gets called.  The test errors out with `Error: timeout of 500ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.` Why does the callback function not get called immediately?

```
var request = require('request');
var sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Job gets data', function(){

    var server;

    beforeEach(function(){
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        server.restore();
    });

    context('When there is a GET request to /something', function(){

        it('will throw an error if response format is invalid', sinon.test(function(done){

            server.respondWith('GET', '/something', [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, '{invalid: "data"}']);
            request.get('/something', function (err, response, body) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(body);
                done();
            });
        }));

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `server.respond` to have all of the requests complete. [I found this Gist which gives an example.](https://gist.github.com/cjohansen/739589)

This is the relevant code.

```
server.respondWith("GET", "/something",
                   [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    '{ "stuff": "is", "awesome": "in here" }']);

var callbacks = [sinon.spy(), sinon.spy()];

jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/something",
  success: callbacks[0]
});

jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/other",
  success: callbacks[1]
});

console.log(server.requests); // Logs all requests so far
server.respond(); // Process all requests so far
```